# How to make sure all the values exist in a table in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table called `FinanceProfilePropertyType`.

It has the following columns:

```
    FinanceProfileId int
    FinanceProfilePropertyTypeId int(PK)
    PropertyTypeId int
```

I have another table called PropertyTypes which has a column PropertyTypeId (int).

Lets say the table PropertyTypes contains data like this:

```
    PropertyTypeId:
      1
      2
      3
```

Now let's say I want to check if the following condition is satisfied: there are rows in FinanceProfilePropertyType table with FinanceProfileId = 1 and PropertyTypeId which contains all the values in PropertyTypes table.

That is I must have all the rows in FinanceProfilePropertyType:

```
FinanceProfilePropertyTypeId  FinanceProfileId  PropertyTypeId
    1                              1                 1
    2                              1                 2
    3                              1                 3
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I dont fully understand your question. To restate what I am reading you want to List all rows where FinanceProfileID = 1 and ONLY the rows where PropertyTypeID maps to a row in propertyTypes table? It seems like what you are trying to do is enforce a foreign key without putting a foreign key on the table.

Comment: [Divided We Stand: The SQL of Relational Division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)